Perpendicularity problem about squares drawn externally on a triangle
I am new to learning euclidean geometry and have beed recently reading the book by Alfred Posamentier called Advanced Euclidean Geometry. I just went through a chapter about the Fermat Point and one of the proposed exercises was the following:
"If squares are constructed externally on the sides of a triangle, prove that the
line containing the centers of any two of these squares is perpendicular to
the line containing the common vertex of these two squares and the center
of the third square."
I have been trying to prove this by using radical axes, I also looked for similar constructions online but I wasn't able to make good use of what I found. I feel as if I don't understand the real relationship between the problem and the theme of the chapter of the book. It would be nice if you could give me any advice on solving this problem!
Here is a graph of the problem I tried to make on GeoGebra.

Try complex bash (represent each point as a complex number and compute the edges)

My first thought was to define the common vertex as $(0,0)$ and then find an expression for the centres of the squares using trigonometry, hoping a nice identity fell out somewhere. Thinking about it now, will post if I find anything worthy.

I've worked out a proof using vectors. It is going to take a while to create diagrams to make a proper answer, but you were looking for a suggestion - so... Vectors.

Complex bash works nicely for this problem (and arguably better than the vectors solution).  $\quad$ The relationship to the Fermat point, is that the synthetic solution is essentially the same diagram (with squares instead of equilatrial triangles).

Preamble: To understand why this is an exercise in the Fermat point chapter, recall the proof of Fermat's point:

Let the circumcircles of equilateral triangles with sides $AB$ and $AC$ intersect at $F$.
Show that $\angle AFB = \angle AFC = 120^\circ$.
Then, since $ \angle BFC = 120^\circ$, hence it lies on the circumcircle of equilateral triangle with sides $BC$.
Show that $\angle BFC = 60^\circ$, hence $AFP$ is a straight line.
Since $AFP$ is the radical axis of our 2 initial circles, hence it is perpendicular to the line containing the centers of the 2 circles, as desired.


Solution: Now, apply a similar diagram to the question at hand and follow the steps above, modified accordingly.
I encourage you to attempt this yourself, before reading on.

 1. Construct squares on $AB$ and $AC$, with circumcircles intersecting at $F$.


 2. Show that $ \angle AFB = \angle AFC = 135^\circ$.


 3.  Since $\angle BFC = 90^\circ$, show that $BFCP$ is cyclic, where $P$ is the center of the third square.


 4. Show that $\angle BFP = 45^\circ$, hence $AFP$ is a straight line.


  5. Since $AFP$ is the radical axis of our 2 initial circles, hence it is perpendicular to the line containing the centers of the 2 circles, as desired.

Note

Where in the proof of fermat's point did we use the assumption that the largest angle is $\leq 120^\circ$? How does this affect the subsequent proof?


@DS Thanks. Fixed.

An alternative construction. First, show that if we erect squares on the sides of a parallelogram, that their centers form a square, most easily seen by a quarter-turn of the red triangle in the diagram on $O_1$ carrying the red dotted line to the blue dotted line. The center of that square must be the midpoint of the diagonal(s) of the parallelogram, marked $M$. So segments to $M$ from any center of a square, e.g., $O_1M$, are equal in length.

Now consider the implications for triangles, viewed as half a parallelogram: $M$ lies equidistant from the centers of the two squares erected on the other sides, and is also equidistant from the center and corner of the square on its side, and a quarter-turn on $M$ establishes the desired result.


Here is another way to prove the third centre lies on the radical axis (using the notation in the diagram below):

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{Pow}_K(J) &= KJ^2 - KB^2 \\
&= BJ^2 - 2BJ\cdot KB \cos(90^\circ+\angle B) \tag{Cosine Rule} \\
&= BJ^2 + 2 \left(\frac{BC}{\sqrt2}\right)\left(\frac{AB}{\sqrt 2}\right)\sin(\angle B) \\
&= BJ^2 + 2(\text{Area of }ABC) \\
&= BJ^2+ 2\left(\frac{BC}{\sqrt2}\right)\left(\frac{AC}{\sqrt 2}\right)\sin(\angle C) \\
&= CJ^2 - 2CJ\cdot LC \cos(90^\circ+\angle C) \\
&= LJ^2 - LC^2 \tag{Cosine Rule} \\
&= \mathrm{Pow}_L(J) \tag*{$\blacksquare$}
\end{align}$$
